# Using roolback/commit colses all cursor, how to over come

Tags: plsql

I have PL/SQL code, where in I am performing Insert into table 1 and based on some condition delete from table2, if delete succeeds then commit all above staments and insert in table3 with status 'cond_true' **else** rollback all above transaction and insert in table3 'cond_false' .  If used commit and rollback within this code, it will close the opened cursor and will have to re-iterate for each cursor again or fail with no cursor open status.

```
OPEN cursor1;       
    Loop            
        fetch cursor1 into tbls;
        exit when cursor1%notfound;                     

            execute immediate  INSERT INTO  table1  SELECT  * FROM table2; 
            -- commit only if below condition is true else rollback;

        BEGIN
            IF  some_condition THEN  
               -- this condition will become true only after the above insert is executed successfully for all rows
                execute immediate   DELETE FROM table2 where some_condition2;

                INSERT INTO table3 values('contition_true');
                -- commit;
            ELSE
                INSERT INTO table3 values('contition_false'); 
                --- first rollback the first insert and then commit only this statement;
            END IF;
        END;
    END LOOP;
close cursor1;
```

Comment: What makes you think the cursor is closed upon commit/rollback? Also, what is the point of the cursor in this particular example? You make no reference to the cursor inside the loop.

Comment: In oracle Rollback and commit, closes all the open cursors. In above case cursor contains table names for table1 and table2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by commit/rollback closes the cursor. Which cursor are you talking about? The cursor that you're looping around, or the delete/insert statements inside the loop?

A commit/rollback will close the transaction, but not the cursor. If that were the case, the following code would error the second time it loops round the cursor, but you'll note that it doesn't:

```
begin
  for rec in (select level lvl from dual connect by level <= 5)
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line('lvl = '||rec.lvl);
    commit;
  end loop;
end;
/

lvl = 1
lvl = 2
lvl = 3
lvl = 4
lvl = 5
```

Perhaps you're talking about fetching across a commit? If so, check out [this AskTom question](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:546822742166).

Or maybe your cursor is `FOR UPDATE`? If so, then doing a commit will release the locks and close the cursor.

As things stand, I can't see any evidence in your example that you need a cursor loop at all (or why you need the execute immediate statements). There appears to be no link between what happens inside the loop with the cursor that generates it. If I were you, I'd try rewriting the whole thing with a series of static set-based delete/inserts, rather than doing everything on a row-by-row basis.

Comment: Thanks Boneist, for loop will work instead of cursor loop. As I said the above given code is a sample of a large dynamic procedure , and it iterates for multiple set of tables and which have different structures; So can't use static statements. Cursor has the table names and column names.